# Political Philosophy and Semantic Metaethics

Tags: ethics, political-philosophy

Ethics is very wide subject matter, and there are so may ways to discuss it as it encompasses a number of fields like psychology, political philosophy, and cultural studies. But the most interesting topics in ethics are metaethics and prescriptive ethics. Metaethics is heavily focused on semantics, proving whether ethical terms are truth apt or not.

Base on my readings, political philosophy tends to discuss ethics in a normative fashion. There is little or no significant connection between semantic metaethics and political philosophy. I mean political philosophy does not care much about the semantic nature and the truth aptness of ethical terms. They are more concerned on the utility and the pragmatic effects of their moral prescriptions. Given that, what are the general comments of some political philosophers, preferably the modern ones, about their lack of interest in semantic metaethics? And, are there any moral or political philosophers who criticize the semantic treatment of metaethics and ethics as a whole?